# DirectoryNotFoundException when using SaveAs (FileUpload)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, path

I have an ASP.NET MVC application and I want to add File Upload functionality.
This is my handler:

```
private void UploadWholeFile(HttpContext context, List<FilesStatus> statuses)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < context.Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            var file = context.Request.Files[i];

            var fullPath = Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_data/UploadedFiles/")) + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

            file.SaveAs(fullPath);

            string fullName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            statuses.Add(new FilesStatus(fullName, file.ContentLength, fullPath));
        }
    }
```

When I test (locally), I'm always getting this error: DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path .....

The strange thing is: I do find the file in the UploadedFiles folder after the test!
So why am I getting this error?

Comment: which line of code is giving exception?

Comment: SaveAs doesn't create new directories. So if you have App_data and don't have UploadedFiles you get this exception. Check firstly does UploadedFiles exist.

Comment: file.SaveAs(fullPath) is giving the exception, and the UploadedFiles folder does really exist, I can even find the file in it after the test...

Comment: I do not see any problem with your code. Because it is running perfectly on my machine. Can you check out your markup? Also can you debug your code locally and see at what iteration and values you are getting that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found out myself what was wrong: after the file was selected for upload, the form was already submitted, resulting in an uploaded file. 
After pressing my 'upload' button, there was an attempt to upload the file again.

So the error message tried to tell me that there was already a file with the same name in that directory!

Answer (score 0):

Comment out these lines of code. One of them is causing your error.

```
string fullName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
statuses.Add(new FilesStatus(fullName, file.ContentLength, fullPath));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
private void UploadWholeFile(HttpContext context, List<FilesStatus> statuses)
{
    string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_data/UploadedFiles/");

    for (int i = 0; i < context.Request.Files.Count; i++)
    {
        var file = context.Request.Files[i];
        file.SaveAs(path + file.FileName);

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try your suggestion, I get the following error (HttpException): .../App_data/UploadedFiles/test.jpg' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected.